# Is it possible to test Google Smart Home in Google Console during developments?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-smart-home

I am experimenting with Google Smart Home. My end goal is to receive home control events, such as `Turn the lights in the living room on`, in my Dialogflow fulfillment service.

I am wondering if it is possible to develop and test Google Smart Home without actual devices. That is, it would be great if I could configure a Google HomeGraph configuration via browser and verify Google Smart Home actions via the console (console.actions.google.com).

Is this possible and practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently it isn't possible to test smart home devices with the web-based Simulator. You will need to [add the device](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying) using the Google Home app on your phone and can then test it using the phone's Assistant.

As an aside, you also can't develop it using Dialogflow directly - you'll need to use the Action SDK. (You can relay it to Dialogflow if you want - but since you just get events and not conversation, it really doesn't help you much.)

Comment: Thank you, very clear for me. I have a follow-up question on that: is it possible to both have a Dialogflow fulfillment endpoint and a action sdk fulfillment endpoint for the same project? As said, everything in my project is in Dialogflow right now, so it would be awesome if I could have the actions sdk integrated in addition, and not as a replacement. If you prefer, I can open a new question for this.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question for that, making it clear what you're currently doing (and what the intents do) and what your webhook looks like.

Comment: Actually prisoner's answer is incomplete. Once you do account linking on your phone you are able to use the web simulator to send commands.